# InvalidArgumentException in JoinClause.php line 79: Not enough arguments for the on clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I did query builder with laravel and I've used multiple join in it. When execute the query I get the error `Not enough arguments for the on clause.`
My query builder:

```
return DB::table('towns_cat_rel')
    ->join('towns', function ($join) {
        $join->on('towns_cat_rel.town_id', '=', 'towns.id')
            ->where('publish', '=', 1);
    })
    ->join('towns_translations', function ($join) {
        $join->on('towns_cat_rel.town_id', '=', 'towns_translations.town_id')
            ->where('locale', '=', \App::getLocale());
    })
    ->join('towns_cat', function ($join) use($categoryID) {
        $join->on('towns_cat.id', '=', 'towns_cat_rel.town_cat_id')
            ->where('towns_cat.id', '=', $categoryID);
    })
    ->join('towns_sub_cat_rel', 'towns_cat_rel.town_id', '=', 'towns_sub_cat_rel.town_id')
    ->join('towns_sub_cat', function ($join) use($subCategoryID) {
        $join->on('towns_sub_cat_rel.town_sub_cat_id', 'towns_sub_cat.id')
            ->where('towns_sub_cat.id', '=', $subCategoryID);
    })
    ->get();
```

Does anyone know why this happen?

Comment: Add =  in second parameter of ON method or follow the link
[Not enough arguments for the on clause laravel](https://sdtuts.com/not-enough-arguments-clause-laravel/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry Guys! I had forget `'='` in the last join =>  `$join->on('towns_sub_cat_rel.town_sub_cat_id', '=', 'towns_sub_cat.id')`
Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I am using laravel5.2 and facing this above error message due to this above code and i resolved with this code, you can modify as per your requirement.

```
    DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', function ($join) {
                $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')->orOn(...);
            })
        ->get();
```